# Is there a way to log automatically the start and end of function definition in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, logging

I want a way to log the beginning and end of the function call without explicitly making a call to a method in log object.

I know we can use `xdebug` to trace the flow, but I have a requirement where I have to make the functions call to be written in the log file without (having code) calling `$logObj->info('Function call');`.

For ex:

```
<?php

class something
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo "Test.";
    }
}

$some = new something();
$some->test();

?>
```

Now, I want to see the following entries in my `out.log`:

```
2010-08-03T09:06:15+02:00 ERR (1): Entering something::test()
...
...
2010-08-03T09:06:15+02:00 ERR (1): Leaving something::test()
```

Comment: I don't really get what you mean with "*we can use `xdebug` to trace the output*", therefore sorry, if what I'll write is already known to you, but we can use xdebug for automatic profiling script execution without doing **any** modifications of source code. All that has to be done - xdebug needs couple of configuration lines in php.ini for enabling profiler and for storing profiling information in some directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is AOP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming )

But PHP doesn't support AOP natively (there are some extensions for it, but I don't know how good they are).

As troelskn mentioned, you should create a wrapper class (**untested**):

```
class LogWrapper
{
    protected $object;

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct($object, $logger)
    {
        $this->object = $object;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) 
    {
        //log
        $returnValue = call_user_func_array(array($this->object, $name), $arguments);
        //log

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post me some of those extensions??

Comment: @rakesh I didn't use any of them ever, just googled 'php aop' and got a bunch of results. Also, now I found a topic here in sf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738282/are-there-any-working-aspect-oriented-php-libraries

Comment: There is a pure PHP library for AOP integration into any existing PHP application: Go! AOP https://github.com/lisachenko/go-aop-php. It doesn't require any PECL-extentions, it neither uses any dark magic of Runkit nor evals, the library doesn't use DI-containers.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper class for your object.

E.g.:

```
class LoggingSomethingWrapper {
  protected $something;
  protected $logger;
  function __construct($something, $logger) {
    $this->something = $something;
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }
  public function test() {
    $this->logger->logBefore(__FUNCTION__);
    $result = $this->something->test();
    $this->logger->logAfter(__FUNCTION__);
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Even better, he can use implement magic methods __call(), __get(), and __set() in the wrapper (instead of explicit proxy methods like test() in your example, and make it nice and generic).

Comment: @Troelskn I don't understand exactly, can you please give me an example implementation?

Comment: @Troelskn like @killer_pl said, I can use `__call()` to make it happen, but it requires a lot of change. I am trying to see is there a way to accomplish this without having modifying the code in bunch of place.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement functions in obcject named as func_xxx. And do a magic method *call() with get a argument xxx, do start logging, calling $this->func*$xxx() and do finish logging

Comment: yep, this is what I had thought of initially, but trying to see if something trendy available in PHP that I could use.